# Maximizing the Magnitude of the Resultant Vector

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, intuition, euclidean-geometry

Given a set of $n$ two-dimensional unit vectors: $\left\{ \mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_n \right\}$, I want to find the coefficients $\left\{ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \right\}$, $0 \leq \alpha_i \leq 1$, that maximize the norm of the resultant vector, i.e. $||\sum_i \alpha_i \mathbf{v}_i||$.

---

**EDIT**

I have managed to show that each $\alpha_i$ must be either $0$ or $1$ (by showing that if $\alpha_i \neq 0$ in the optimal solution, then the norm of the resultant vector is strictly increasing in $\alpha_i$). The problem therefore reduces to finding the optimal combination of $\alpha_i$'s from $2^n$ possibilities.

However, I believe that the search could be narrowed down much further (at least in two dimensions). My intuition tells me that the subset of vectors that feature in the optimal solution must lie in a half plane. The search would then become $\mathcal{O} (n^2)$.

Alas, a proof eludes me.

Comment: An easy way to show that $\alpha_i = 0, 1$, is to prove that if $A, B, C$ are 3 consecutive points in a line, then for any point $X$, $|XB| \leq \max ( |XA|, |XC|)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know all coefficients are either 0 or 1 based on some answers and your own observations. So to get an $O(n^2)$ time solution, it suffices to prove that the vectors in the optimal solution are contiguous when the original set of vectors are ordered according to angle circularly. For this first we prove a lemma.

Lemma: The set of vectors in an optimal solution using a minimal number of vectors must all lie in an open half-plane.

Proof: Suppose not. Then it is easy to see that there is a non-trivial non-negative combination of the vectors in the optimal solution $\sum_i c_i v_i$ that equals zero. Whichever $c_i$ is the largest, say $c_1$, we have that vector $v_1$ will effectively be cancelled out in the optimal solution, and the remaining vectors will effectively have either equal or lower coefficients. Thus by leaving out $v_1$ we can get an optimal solution using a fewer number of vectors, a contradiction. Thus all vectors in an optimal solution must lie in a common half-plane if the optimal solution uses a minimal number of vectors.

Using the lemma, we can prove the optimal solution using the minimal number of vectors is a contiguous set of vectors. To see this, suppose we have an optimal solution with minimal number of vectors where the set of vectors is not contiguous. Then there are two vectors $v_1,v_2$ in the optimal solution, and a third vector $w$ in between them which is not included in the optimal solution. Let $z$ be the summation vector for the optimal solution. Then depending on which side of $w$ that $z$ is on, either $w$ is closer to $z$ than $v_1$ (in the sense of angle) or closer to $z$ than $v_2$ (because $z,v_1,v_2,w$ all lie in a common open hyperplane). Suppose it is $v_1$. Then consider $z - v_1$. We know that adding $v_1$ improves the solution, so the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ becomes positive for some $\alpha < 1$ for the length of the vector $(z-v_1) + \alpha v_1$. But $w$ is closer to $z$ than $v_1$ is, so adding $w$ to the optimal solution $z$ is certainly better than adding a multiple of $v_1$ which is the same length as $w$, and this is equivalent to increasing $\alpha$ to a value greater than 1. But we know the derivative of the length of $(z- v_1) + \alpha v_1$ is positive for $\alpha > 1$ because the derivative is increasing. Thus adding $w$ improves the optimal solution even further, a contradiction. So $w$ must be in the optimal solution, and hence the vectors in the optimal solution using a minimal number of vectors are contiguous when ordered according to angle circularly.

Comment: This looks like the right answer. I'll go through it in detail to make sure everything's in order, but it looks good. Out of curiousity, do you think that generalizing this to higher dimensions would be (a) trivial, (b) complicated or (c) impossible?

Comment: @MGA For higher dimensions, the optimal solution is still 0/1 so next question is whether all the vectors must be in a common half-space if the number of vectors in the optimal solution is minimal. I think this is true but I'm not sure. However, even if that's established I think it would be complicated to derive an algorithm. There's no easy sense of "contiguous" in dimensions $d \geq 3$ (there are at least two degrees of freedom to move around in). Maybe you could prove that if $d$ vectors are in the solution and a vector $w$ is in the cone spanned by them, then $w$ is in the solution too.

Comment: If it's true that whenever there are vectors in the optimal solution that span a cone then all vectors inside the cone are also in the optimal solution, then one algorithm is to enumerate all subsets of vectors that are extremal meaning no vector is "in the middle" of the cone. In dimension $2$ this is just quadratic complexity, and I'm not sure what the complexity is in dimension $3$. If it's not bad (say, quadratic or cubic instead of exponential) then that would give you a good brute force search algorithm, you could probably use a triangulation to efficiently enumerate the extremal sets.

Comment: Nevermind, if you choose all the vectors in 3d to have the same length and lie on the boundary of a traditional cone, then every subset of vectors is extremal so the number of extremal sets is exponential, making brute force search over extremal sets a bad idea. I think it's really hard in dimensions 3 and higher. Maybe somebody else can lend some insight.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that in an optimal solution, all coefficients $\alpha_i$  are either $0$ or $1$. To see this, suppose you have an optimal solution with some $\alpha_i$ satisfying $0 < \alpha_i < 1$. Then this solution is better than setting $\alpha_i = 0$, and it can be shown that this implies that the objective function is strictly increasing as $\alpha_i$ increases, so $\alpha_i = 1$ gives an even better solution. The next thing to note is that if you have an optimal solution where two $\alpha_i$ are non-zero for two vectors lying in a common half-space, and there is another vector lying in between the two vectors in that half-space, then you must have $\alpha_i = 1$ for the middle vector as well. This is shown by showing that if two vectors in a common half space improve the objective function, then any angle in between the two vectors also improves the objective function. So you only need to search over the $O(n^2)$ subsets of vectors that are consecutive when ordered circularly by angle. Find the best subset when all coefficients for the subset are set to $1$, and you have your optimal solution.

Comment: Are you sure about your statement regarding a vector in between two vectors that are in a half-space? While its scalar products with those two vectors are positive, it might have negative scalar products with other vectors outside that half-plane. Can we ensure that the net contribution to the objective function is still positive?

Comment: "strictly increasing as $\alpha_i$ increases" is not quite true, for small values of $\alpha_i$. E.g. Take $v_1 = (1,-1)$, $v_2 = (0,3)$ and $\alpha_1 = 1, \alpha_2 = 0.8$.

Answer (score 1):

just to give you a different and possibly more general point of view:  let $v_i= (sin\theta_i, \cos\theta_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, and $V=[v_1,v_2...]$, then your problem is

$\max || v_0 ||^2$
s.t.
$ v_0 = V\alpha $,
$ \alpha_i \in [0,1]$

or more compactly

$\max \frac{1}{2} \alpha^T V^T V \alpha $
s.t.
$ \alpha_i \in [0,1]$

From the optimality conditions you can easily see that either $\alpha_i=0$ or $\alpha_i=1$. The problem is not convex, since your are maximizing a convex function (any norm is so). So if you write down the Lagrangian function you have

$L(\alpha, \lambda_l,\lambda_u)= \frac{1}{2} \alpha^T V^T V \alpha - \lambda_l^T\alpha + \lambda_u^T(\alpha - 1)$

Imposing the KKT conditions you get that $\alpha\in (0,1)$ implies $\lambda_u= \lambda_l= 0$ and hence $V^TV \alpha=0$ which is possible only for $\alpha=0$, being $Z=V^TV$ positive definite. This shows that the solution must be on boundary.

To see that you must be on a corner, you can use the very definition of maximum: let $i$ such that $\alpha_i\in (0,1)$, you can verify that at least one among $\alpha + e_i$ and $\alpha - e_i$ is an ascending direction. Only in a corner you can have only feasible descent direction.

But I think you should look for details on some textbook.

I think that this is in fact a combinatorial problem, and that probably there are no efficient algorithms.

Comment: I think you're wrong in the statement about positive scalar products. Take two vectors such that the angle between them is strictly between 90 and 120 degrees. Their scalar product is negative; yet adding them together gives a vector with a norm larger than one.

Answer (score 0):

[Work in progress, there are some issues.]

First, we know that the maximum occurs when $\alpha_i = 0 $ or $1$. An easy way to show this, is to prove that if $A, B, C$ are 3 consecutive points in a line, then for any point $X$, $|XB| \leq \max ( |XA|, |XC|)$.

Next, consider the vector $v = \frac{1}{2} \sum v_i$.

We want to compare vectors of the form $ v + \sum \beta_i v_i$, where $ \beta_i = \frac{1}{2}$ or $- \frac{1}{2}$.

It makes most sense to use $\beta_i = \frac{1}{2}$ if $v_i \cdot v \geq 0 $, as that allows you to extend it further out.

Answer (score 0):

This [problem](https://szkopul.edu.pl/problemset/problem/NZSCUwz2ACePsBKuVCIVzrRt/site/?key=statement) was given during the first stage of the Polish Olympiad in Informatics (October-November 2017). Other answers here give a $O(n^2)$ solution (check all subarrays of the vectors ordered by angle), but $O(n \log n)$ is possible ($O(n)$ after sorting the vectors).

Let $v$ be the sorted array of vectors and $p$ be the prefix sum of this sorted array. For any $n < m, p_m - p_n$ is the sum $\Sigma_{i=n+1}^m v_i$. So the answer to the original problem translates to finding the pair $i, j$ such that $||p_j - p_i||$ is maximal.

Now we have a set of points $p$ and want to find the greatest distance between any pair. There is a known algorithm for that called [rotating calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers). It uses a technique called "two pointers" or "caterpillar" for finding all antipodal points of the polygon. Note that we don't need to calculate the convex hull of $p$, because it's already "kinda convex" - no proof for that, sorry. Intuitively, the vectors were initally sorted and any big jumps in angle or intersections in the polygon won't break the algorithm.

But the answer could be vectors from the beginning and from the end of $v$ because we picked the smallest angle arbitrarily, and that can't be represented as a difference of two elements in $p$ like before. In reality, we don't keep the array $p$:

C++

```
n = v.size();
long long sx = v[0].x, sy = v[0].y;
long long result = sx*sx + sy*sy;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (j < i) {
        j = i;
        sx = v[i].x; sy = v[i].y;
        result = max(result, sx*sx + sy*sy);
    }
    while ((j+1)%n != i && v[i].x * v[(j+1)%n].y - v[i].y * v[(j+1)%n].x >= 0) {
        j++;
        sx += v[j%n].x; sy += v[j%n].y;
        result = max(result, sx*sx + sy*sy);
    }
    sx -= v[i].x; sy -= v[i].y;
    result = max(result, sx*sx + sy*sy);
}
```